# Accessing args in Perl Hash Ref

Tags: perl, hashref, hash-reference

```
$self->doSomething({
    record     => $record,
    listing    => [ $foo, $bar, $baz ],
    passedargs => { something => $val, another => $val2 }
});
```

accessing args within a hashref.

So if I wanted to access record I would

```
my $record = $args->{record};
```

If I wanted to access listing I would

```
my @listing = $args->{listing};
```

How would I access Passedargs? If I just wanted to access "something" or "another"?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want assign the values in `listing` to an array, please note that you'll need to dereference it:

```
my @listing = @{ $args->{listing} };
```

To access the fields in `passedargs`, you simply need to use the following syntax:

```
my $something = $args->{passedargs}{something};
```

For more details, take a look at: [perldsc - Perl Data Structures Cookbook](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html)

Comment: Re "If you want assign the values in listing to an array", you probably want the wrong thing :) Usually, `my $listing = $args->{listing};` is far more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

`$args->{passedargs}` is a hashref itself, so you would do:

```
my $something = $args->{passedargs}->{something};
```